# Intel SSD toolbox fails, reports "error connecting to drive"

Tags: ssd

When using the SSD toolbox to manually run trim, the toolbox loads but then says its "unable to connect to drive".  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Asking/answering my own question is kind of lame, I'm doing this for the next time I have this issue it doesn't take me so long to rediscover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is suggested here: http://communities.intel.com/message/78539;jsessionid=48A13DE8B18CD478528559087E625352.node5COMS

The helpful message is from Polo127.  Note that he installs then uninstalls the nVidia driver if its nnot already present..  I would never have guessed:

I ran into the same problem with my Asus nForce 650. There was another response from BorderShot with the solution. Here it is:

> Alright, I got this to work by
>   changing the driver from the "NVIDIA
>   nForce Serial ATA Controller" to the
>   generic "Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE
>   Controller".  In Vista, Control Panel
>   --> System --> Device Manager, IDE ATA/ATAPI Controllers, select "NVIDIA
>   nForce Serial ATA Controller", right
>   click, Properties, Driver, Update
>   Driver, Browse My Computer, Let me
>   pick from a list, and then select the
>   "Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE
>   Controller".  After reboot, I was able
>   to use the SSD Toolbox.
>
> I didnt have the Nvidia nForce serial
>   ata controller driver so i just
>   decided to update the standard duel
>   pci ide controller and rebooted
>   anyways BUT it did NOT help at all. SO
>   I went to nvidia's site to download
>   the lastest nForce driver which did
>   install the nforce serial controller
>   then I followed BorderShot's
>   instruction and it worked like a
>   charm! I am now able to see and TRIM
>   the drive.
>
> Let me know if you have any
>   questions.